# How to move text output of php in html

Tags: php, html, css

I have a php code block related to account login logout etc. However, when I log in without a valid password it echos "Please enter a valid username/password" However, when the text does appear, it is covered by my  HTML scripts, I dont know if I can position it? Or do I have to convert it to HTML scripts, please enligten me Thanx x

this is where the output is coming from

```
   <!D0CTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>

        <style>
        #lions {
        position:absolute;
        top:15px;
        left:1200px;
        z-index:9;

        }
        </style>




        </head>




        </html>
        <?php if (isset($_POST['username'])&&isset($_POST['password'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $password_hash = md5($password);

        if(!empty($username)&&!empty($password)){
            $query = "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE     `username`='".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."' AND `password`='".mysql_real_escape_string($password_hash)."'";

            if ($query_run = @mysql_query($query)){
                $query_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query_run);

                if($query_num_rows == 0){
                    echo 'Invalid Username/Password!';

                }else if ($query_num_rows == 1){

        $user_id = mysql_result($query_run, 0 ,'id');
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
        header('Location: index.php');
                }           







            }




        }else{
            echo 'You must enter Username/Password!';

        }
        }

        ?>

        <div id="lions">
        <form action ="<?php echo $current_file; ?>" method="POST">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username"> Password:<input        type="password" name="password">
        <input type ="submit" value="Log in">
        </form>
        </div>
This is the main page

<!D0CTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> VolunNear </title>
<meta charset = "utf-8">
<link rel = "stylesheet" href ="stylex.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<?php
require 'core.inc.php';
require 'connect.inc.php';
    if(loggedin()){
        $fname= getuserfield('firstname');
        $sname= getuserfield('surname');
        echo 'You\'re logged in as '. $fname.' '.$sname. '<a href="logout.php"> Log out</a>';


    }else{
include 'loginform.inc.php';        
    }


?>
</head>


<body>

<h1 id="id1"> <span class="span1">Volun</span><span class="spanx">Near</span> </h1>

 <div id="nav"> 
<div id="nav_wrapper">

<ul>

<li><a href="#">Volunteering LeaderBoard</a>
</li> 
<li><a href="#">Hour tracker</a>
</li> 
<li><a href="#">Non-profits </a>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Contact us</a>

 <ul>

<li><a href="#"> Look here</a>
</li>
<li><a href="#"> Contact form</a>
</li>
<li><a href="#"> suggestion form</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Hour Log</a>
<ul>

    <li><a href="#">Your hours</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Ontario Regulations</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </li>



</li>










</li>

</ul>



</body>





</html>
```

Comment: How can we help you with out knowing what you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Echo will output exactly where it has been placed in the code, so if your php script is calling the echo BEFORE your html is output, the echoed string will appear above the html.

If you want the message to be within the html, as it should, you should instead place the message in a variable, and then within your html, call the echo wherever you would like the message to appear.

But as @Andre stated, without the actual code, it's hard to give you a clear example.

```
<?php
$my_message = 'Please enter a valid username/password';
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
   <div id="error_message">
      <?= $my_message; ?>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Something along those lines, super basic example.

Comment: perhaps i'm just mean, but even an attempt to answer such a question is counter productive.

Comment: @Dagon even if it helps him understand his problem? Definitely not a necessary downvote to me.. downvote the question, but if my answer helps him solve his problem, then why should I be penalized.

Comment: why not just wait for clarification, if your desperate to answer some question, there are many more open ones that are clearly asked.

Comment: @Dagon because I understood what is problem was, gave him my solution, but I couldn't put it in the context of his exact code because he didn't provide it.